# Parse part of url- python

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

I have two types of addresses in DataBase:

```
url_1  = "http://country.city.street/"
url_2  = "http://country.city.street:8180/"
```

I need to get a uniform address format (`url_pattern = "country.city.street"`) to use in a DNS server. I removed the `http://` part from the beginning but can't get a good result with the end of the address. Does anyone have an idea what I could use to get a `url_pattern` standard?

```
url_1  = "http://country.city.street/"
url_2  = "http://country.city.street:8180/"

url_1 = url_1[7:]
url_2 = url_2[7:]
```

Comment: Your current solution is problematic if you have an `https://...` address.

Comment: You could use `split()` a few times: `url = address.split('/')[2].split(':')[0]`.

Comment: I know, but this infrastructure use ony http://, https:// will never be used - strange for me ;)

Comment: Or you could go full-on regular expression: `match = re.search(r'//(?P<base>.+?[:/])', address); url = match.group(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is standard module for URL parsing

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
print(urlparse("http://country.city.street:8180/").hostname)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use *`urllib.parse`* module. It has a [*`urlparse` function*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) that you could use to parse a URL [into components](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse).

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.urlparse("http://country.city.street/")
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='country.city.street', path='/', params='', query='', fragment='')
```